# is it possible in pandas to treat (NULL) non-existing index/value as 0 in diff operation?

Tags: python, pandas

For example below

d1 has **d1.KRK.ANDROID == 600**, while d2 has no such index. Is it possible to treat absense of such index/value as 0 in d2 - d1?

Right now operation returns NaN.

Is the only option to manually go and define such index and zero value? So I need to get d2-d1 to have -600 for KRK.ANDROID instead of NaN.

```
d2=pd.DataFrame({'branch':['EKB','KRK','NB','VN'],
                  'worktype':['PHP','PYTHON','PYTHON','ANDROID'],
                  'minutes':[20, 270, 20, 20]})\
      .set_index(['branch', 'worktype'])

d1=pd.DataFrame({'branch':['EKB','KRK','KRK','KRK', 'NB', 'VN'],
                  'worktype':['PHP','ANDROID','PYTHON','QA', 'PYTHON', 'ANDROID'],
                  'minutes':[20, 600, 680, 45, 120, 15]})\
      .set_index(['branch', 'worktype'])

In [293]: d2
Out[293]: 
                 minutes
branch worktype         
EKB    PHP            20
KRK    PYTHON        270
NB     PYTHON         20
VN     ANDROID        20

In [294]: d1
Out[294]: 
                 minutes
branch worktype         
EKB    PHP            20
KRK    ANDROID       600
       PYTHON        680
       QA             45
NB     PYTHON        120
VN     ANDROID        15

In [295]: d2 - d1
Out[295]: 
                 minutes
branch worktype         
EKB    PHP           0.0
KRK    ANDROID       NaN
       PYTHON     -410.0
       QA            NaN
NB     PYTHON     -100.0
VN     ANDROID       5.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `reindex` :-)

```
d2.reindex(d1.index).fillna(0)-d1
Out[342]: 
                 minutes
branch worktype         
EKB    PHP           0.0
KRK    ANDROID    -600.0
       PYTHON     -410.0
       QA          -45.0
NB     PYTHON     -100.0
VN     ANDROID       5.0
```

For you additional requirement

```
if len(d2.index.labels[1])<len(d1.index.labels[1]):
    print(d2.reindex(d1.index).fillna(0) - d1)
else :
    print(d2 - d1.reindex(d2.index).fillna(0))
```

Updated 2

```
AAA=set(d1.index.tolist()+d2.index.tolist())
d1.reindex(AAA).fillna(0)-d2.reindex(AAA).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Wen - thank you! It worked for my particular scenario, but only because d1 has more values in its index. For example ```d1.reindex(d2.index).fillna(0)-d2``` removes a lot of elements, while it should keep them. ANy ideas?

Comment: @DmitrySemenov could you please show the case you mentioned ?

Comment: @DmitrySemenov `d1-d2.reindex(d1.index).fillna(0)` ?

Comment: but this requires to know which of d1 or d2 has bigger index. So either uou do d1.reindex - d2 or d1 - d2.reindex depends on index values in d1 and d2

Comment: now what if both d1 and d2 contains unique indexes? https://gist.github.com/dmitry-saritasa/2f6e4d1514a6dc71d528fc5ce8d76ba3 for example here NB.PM has 199 which is missed after the diff.

Comment: @DmitrySemenov Updated

Comment: Interesting! Thanks Wen!

Answer (score 0):

I found another way is to use **df.diff()** when you need to find difference over date/time index. I.e. how specific value changes every day. I just had to convert the original groupby dataframe into pure 2D dataframe without using multindex

```
In [912]: gp = gp.unstack(level=1).fillna(0) 
In [913]: with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', 3):
     ...:     print(gp)
     ...:     
department  MOBILE  ...      WEB
period              ...         
2016-02-03     0.0  ...     30.0
2016-12-24     0.0  ...    400.0
2016-12-25     0.0  ...     80.0
2016-12-26     0.0  ...     20.0
2016-12-27     0.0  ...    180.0
2016-12-28   600.0  ...     15.0
2017-01-01     0.0  ...    190.0
2017-01-03     0.0  ...     80.0
2017-01-04    20.0  ...      0.0
2017-02-01   120.0  ...      0.0
2017-02-02    45.0  ...      0.0

In [914]: with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', 3):
     ...:     print(gp.diff())
     ...:     
     ...:     
department  MOBILE  ...      WEB
period              ...         
2016-02-03     NaN  ...      NaN
2016-12-24     0.0  ...    370.0
2016-12-25     0.0  ...   -320.0
2016-12-26     0.0  ...    -60.0
2016-12-27     0.0  ...    160.0
2016-12-28   600.0  ...   -165.0
2017-01-01  -600.0  ...    175.0
2017-01-03     0.0  ...   -110.0
2017-01-04    20.0  ...    -80.0
2017-02-01   100.0  ...      0.0
2017-02-02   -75.0  ...      0.0

[11 rows x 4 columns]
```